# Show restricted youtube videos in YoutubePlayerFragment?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

When i play certain videos am getting error showing "this video contains content from wmg.it is restricted from playback on certain sites"

Does anyone have idea to play this video in my player?

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says :

`This video contains content from WMG. It is restricted from playback on certain sites`

It means the video contains content from `WMG` and they decide what types of embedding are allowed & not allowed and it may depend upon the host site on whether it is or isn't allowed.

**[More Details](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/DoHpPX94oEA)**